# Homelab SAN, I need advices

Tags: home-networking, iscsi, san

I'd like to add a SAN to my homelab for learning / fun purpose, so I have spend the last few days trying to learn more about it but as some infos are pretty old and there is a lot a different technologies, I am bit afraid of getting tangled up...

Here is how I see things and I'd like you to correct me if I misunderstand something :)

There seems to have two majors ways of transporting data between the SAN and the servers/workstations :
iSCSI which is a network layer used to transport raw disk data over a LAN (generally a 10 Gbps one for performance).
 - Fibre Channel which is a dedicated "network" to connect SAN and devices via a FC switch.

iSCSI is the cheapest way if LAN is already equipped with 10 Gbps but if not, I can find cheap 8Gbps FC switch on ebay.

Controllers is where I have a lot of confusion... Inside the SAN I will of course need a raid controller to build the arrays and logical volumes (I currently use HP P410 ones). If I use iSCSI it will require a additional 10Gbps NIC controller and the OS (like Openfiler) will do the rest, right ?
But if I go for fibre channel, do I simply need HBA controller (say 2 ports) in the SAN to connect with HBA controllers inside the servers ? Is that as simple as that ?

Because I see some controllers with both internals and externals ports, is that an requirement to use them of can I go with my existing raid controllers and add an HBA ?

I also would like to share with you how I see my homelab infrastructure but first I'd like to know if I am on the right way :)

Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: Also think about what the SAN is connecting to. You talk about a 10GB iSCSI connection but what is on the other end? The only reason to build a SAN is to connect multiple hosts to the same backend storage. If you don't have multiple 10GB hosts then you are adding a bunch of network hardware between you and the disk for no reason.

Comment: Of course. There will be two servers and a workstation.

Comment: As I see, HP P410 has SAS interfaces only, so this is direct-attached storage. To bring this enclosure to SAN either iSCSI or FC you need to connect it with a host, which will serve as a storage system. This storage system must be able to propagate SCSI targets over FC or iSCSI so the clients can connect. The methods of how to set targets very much depend on the storage system OS, HBAs and protocols so look at FreeBSD/Linux Storage/NAS oriented distributions or, as I remember, there was even Windows Storage server edition.